# AWS Security Group, if open to all ingress ports, can it be externally accessed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, network-programming, aws-glue

In order to use a glue job that writes data into an RDS instance in a VPC, I need to have a self referencing security group (done) and I need a security group that is also open to all ingress ports. If I do this, does that allow for external access? Haven't really found a concrete answer in the docs.

Comment: You said open to all ingress PORTS. But not all IPs, right? So as long as IP is restricted to either another security group or your CIDR block then no it doesn't. Also, if there isn't an internet gateway connected, then it wouldn't matter how open the SG is because no one can enter the network

Comment: Right, it's just all ports and the source is the security group that's self referencing. There is an internet gateway attached which is why I want to make sure.

Comment: Yeah, so anything launched with that SG attached would be able to access. Or anything able to route communication through an instance with that SG. Which could be an attack vector. But you can mitigate that with IAM Roles, etc.

Comment: Just wondering why don't you move the rds instance to private

Comment: @ArunK not sure what you mean? It's a private RDS instance within a VPC

Comment: You said there is an internet gateway attached. A subnet with an internet gateway is public.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a [VPC endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/vpc-endpoint.html) for Glue.

If your security groups open to all ingress ports, and your endpoint exposes a public IP address and you haven't implemented any custom network ACL / firewall rules, you will most likely make the RDS instance publicly accessible.

EDIT: Saw clarification in comments re: self-referencing sg. If you are only allowing traffic from the sg, you will not be exposing your RDS instance to the public. You will only be exposing your RDS instance to clients within the VPC.

Comment: Tried adding the VPC endpoint for Glue but it's still failing to connect. Also,I appreciate the edit. Networking is not my wheelhouse so I'm being extra careful. But from what I gather as long as the SG is self referencing it doesn't matter what ports it's open to, right?